# truffle is using 5777 as default network_id

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

ganache is using 1337 as the network Id but truffle keeps using 5777 by default,how do i change this?

truffle-config.js

```
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');




module.exports={
    networks:{
        developments:{
            host:"HTTP://127.0.0.1:",
            port:'7545',
            network_id:'*'
        },
    },
    contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
    contracts_build_directory: './src/truffle_abis',
    compilers:{
        solc:{
            version : '^0.5.0',
            optimizer:{
                enabled: true,
                runs:200
            },
        }
    }
}
```

error message

```
Error: The network id specified in the truffle config (5777) does not match the one returned by the network (1337).  Ensure that both the network and the provider are properly configured.
    at Object.detectAndSetNetworkId (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\environment\environment.js:111:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at Object.detect (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\environment\environment.js:24:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate\run.js:22:1)
    at Command.run (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command.js:189:1)
Truffle v5.4.25 (core: 5.4.25)
Node v14.17.6
```

Comment: The network id is not the chain id, the default chain id is 1337 and u should add it in your config

Comment: i have done this but i still get the same error.

Comment: my tip is move to hardhat. Truffle did a great job for years but hardhat is more configurable and easier now

Answer (score 0):

i spelt developments instead of development so truffle couldn't read the parameters

and also added HTTP to the host

```
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');


module.exports={
    networks:{
        development:{
            host:"127.0.0.1",
            port:'7545',
            network_id:'*'
        },
    },
    contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
    contracts_build_directory: './src/truffle_abis',
    compilers:{
        solc:{
            version : '^0.5.0',
            optimizer:{
                enabled: true,
                runs:200
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to configure it in the Settings menu? I also have different network_id with Ganache and Truffle but never experienced error like that.

[image: settings ganache]